# Loading json file to chartjs

Tags: javascript, json, chart.js

I'm trying to load a json file (static file) to chartjs. but it's not giving any result back.I'm using python to generate the json file.
I'm new to jquery and javascript.

this is my code looks like.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Bar Chart</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="static/js/chart-min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="static/js/util.js"></script>
    <style>
    canvas {
        -moz-user-select: none;
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        -ms-user-select: none;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<script>
    <div id="container" style="width: 75%;">
        <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
    </div>

$.getJSON( "var/graph.json", function( data ) {
 var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
 type: 'bar',
 data: data,
 options: {
    scales: {
        yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
                beginAtZero: true
            }
        }]
    }
  }
 });

</script>

</body>

</html>
```

My static json file looks like this

```
{
    "test_data": [
        ["aa", "11"],
        ["bb", "123"],
        ["cc", "81"],
        ["dd", "12"],
        ["ee", "22"]
    ]
}
```

What i'm missing here...i need to draw a line graph (x Axis - name (aa,bb,cc,dd) y Axis numbers (11,123,81,22)
Appreciate your help on this.

Answer (score 2):

---

```
$.getJSON("var/graph.json", function(data) {
   var labels = data.test_data.map(function(e) {
      return e[0];
   });
   var data = data.test_data.map(function(e) {
      return e[1];
   });

var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
   var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
      type: 'line',
      data: {
         labels: labels,
         datasets: [{
            backgroundColor: 'rgb(129, 198, 2228)',
            borderColor: 'rgb(0, 150, 215)',
            data: data
         }]
      },
      options: {
         responsive: 'true',
      }
   });
});
</script>
```

---

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" height="80"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to transform the `data` into a format suitable for a [linear chart axis](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/linear.html). For your line chart, you need to define `labels` and the `data` of the dataset. This can be done using the [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method.

```
data: {
  labels: data.test_data.map(a => a[0]),
  datasets: [{
      data: data.test_data.map(a => a[1]),
      ...
    }]
  },
```

Please have a look at your amended code below.

```js
const data = {
  "test_data": [
    ["aa", "11"],
    ["bb", "123"],
    ["cc", "81"],
    ["dd", "12"],
    ["ee", "22"]
  ]
};

new Chart('canvas', {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: data.test_data.map(a => a[0]),
    datasets: [{
      label: 'My Dataset',
      data: data.test_data.map(a => a[1]),
      fill: false,
      borderColor: 'red'
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" height="80"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks. How can i load this from an external json file without adding const data, what i'm doing is use python to generate the json file and store in a directory, then my chartjs need to load the file and plot the graph.

Comment: @Markus: I answered the part related to JavaScript and Chart.js. Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/a/45273953/2358409 provides some help about `$.getJSON() `