# generating a Chart.js chart with python data

Tags: python, chart.js

I am working on a litte stock-market project in Python.
Every week, a status.xlsx file is generated that tells me what sectors make up my portfolio, e.g.

```
xls = pd.ExcelFile('Status_week_9.xlsx')
df1=pd.read_excel(xls)
print(df1)
```

I am looping over all files, so I get a dataframe similar to this for every file:

```
sector              pct              
Consumer Cyclical   0.319638
Industrials         0.203268
Financial Services  0.200217
...
```

Now I would like to loop through these weekly reports and pass the data to a Chart.js template in order to get a stacked bar for each week that shows the increase / decrease of sectors over time, e.g. https://jsfiddle.net/qg1ya5vk/4/ (demo only, does not add up to 1)

The template file looks like this:

The idea was to use a template with placeholders for the chart and use

```
from string import Template
```

to replace the placeholders with the corresponding values.
The variables are "labels" and "dataset". "Labels" consists of the calendar weeks. This can be extracted from the filenames. So far, so good ;-)

Now for the "dataset", I'm not sure how to get information from the n dataframes.

One dataset would have to look like this:

```
 {label: 'Energy',
           data: [0.037975, 0.038512, 0.039817, 0.065010],}
```

So this would mean that the Energy sector had a share of 3.7975% in week 1, 3.8512% in week 2 etc. Complicating things even further, it's also possible that one sector is not present in one week, so I would have to add a 0 then, because the sector is not part of the original dataframe.

There can be n (comma-separated) datasets.

I probably have to transpose the dataframe but it doesn't quite do the trick (yet).

So far my code looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
import os
from string import Template

labels=[]
dataset=[]
files =...
for i in files:
    cw = i.split('_')[3].split('.')[0] ## extract calendar week from filename
    xls = pd.ExcelFile(i)
    df1 = pd.read_excel(xls, 'Sectors') ## select sheet 'Sectors'
    df1['CW'] = cw   ## add cw to df1
    df1_t = df1.T. ## transpose df1
    sectors = df1.sector.to_list()
    share = df1.pct.to_list()
    labels.append(cw)
    dataset.append(df1_t) ##??


# {
#       label: 'Energy',
#       data: [0.037975, 0.038512, 0.039817, 0.065010],
#     }


d = {'label' : labels, 'datasets' : dataset}

## open Chart template and put in values:
with open('template.txt', 'r') as f:
    src = Template(f.read())
    result = src.substitute(d)
    print(result)
```

How would you generate the datasets?

I am also thinking this is a little bit long-winded and error-prone. Maybe there is another way to tackle this?

Template for chart:

```
var label = $label;
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart4").getContext('2d');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: label,
    datasets: [
    $datasets      //**this is the culprit**
  ],
  },
options: {
    tooltips: {
      displayColors: true,
      callbacks:{
        mode: 'x',
      },
    },
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        stacked: true,
        gridLines: {
          display: false,
        }
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        stacked: true,
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true,
        },
        type: 'linear',
      }]
    },
    responsive: true,
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    legend: { position: 'bottom' },
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is the [json](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) module. You can simply arrange your data in the correct form in python and write to a JSON that Chart.js can understand.

```py
import json

data = {'label' : labels, 'datasets' : dataset}
with open('data.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(data, f)
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45273313/use-json-file-with-chart-js) question is about how to get your JSON into Chart.js.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting json! Just to be clear, does this mean I would have to create a JSON file from the xlsx-files/dataframes and then use the JSON with Charts.js?

Comment: Yes basically. What you are doing gets close but the problem is that `Template` does not know how to turn python dict into a string in the way that you expect it to do.